# Why I cannot declare objects for inner classes in the way mentioned in code?

Tags: java, class, nested

This code is working properly.However, when i try to change the position of inner class object ,the code isn't working

```
class Outer {
    int outer_x = 100;

    void test() {
        for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
            class Inner {
                void display() {
                    System.out.println("display: outer_x = " + outer_x);
                }
            }

            //when i create oject for Inner class here code is working
            Inner inner = new Inner();
            inner.display();
        }
    }
}

class InnerClassDemo {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Outer outer = new Outer();
        outer.test();
    }
}
```

But when i place Inner class object as in the code below ,code is not working. The IDE was not able to find the inner class while declaring the inner class below its instance

```
class Outer {
    int outer_x = 100;

    void test() {
        for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
            //now i created object for inner class here
            Inner inner = new Inner();
            inner.display();

            class Inner {
                void display() {
                    System.out.println("display: outer_x = " + outer_x);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

class InnerClassDemo {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Outer outer = new Outer();
        outer.test();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please indent your code consistently if you are asking people to try and read it.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Actually you can. The first example compiles just fine. The problem is that in the second example, the class is defined after it is used.

Comment: @marstran: Wow. And...wow. Moreover: Wow.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder It surprised me as well when I found out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second example, you define the `Inner` class after it is used. It is not available yet when you do `new Inner()`.

Anyway, I would say it is bad practice to create (named) classes within for-loops like this (or even within methods). Anonymous classes are usually fine though. When you need a named class you usually want to define it either in the scope of the class, or in a file by it self.

Comment: thanks @marstran .Thanks for indenting code. I am new here. How can i indent code?

Comment: If you use an IDE, you can usually use some hotkey to automatically do it (ctrl-shift-F in Eclipse, or ctrl-alt-L in IntelliJ). If you don't, you just need to use your spacebar/tab to do it manually :)

Answer (score 0):

Understand it this way...Suppose you want new cool looking,stylish IPhone 7,so you went to the store and saw that your IPhone is still being unloaded from truck.So you went in and told the person at counter that you want IPhone 7,but that person said to you **"Sorry sir,we are out of stock"** , because that person doesn't know that it is still being unloaded.Same thing is happening here, you know there is **Inner class** in your code,but compiler doesn't know it.SO it throws error.